# Ruby methods to enable and disable attributes

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby code segment which I need to DRY up. Can it be done without meta programming?

```
def disable_attribute
  statement1
  @response = Client::Service.disable_attribute(
    param1: param1value,
    param2: param2value
  )   
  statement2
end

def enable_attribute
  statement1
  @response = Client::Service.enable_attribute(
    param1: param1value,
    param2: param2value
  )   
  statement2
end
```

Comment: those methods have no arguments for the attribute that's being updated?

Comment: "Without metaprogramming"? This is per definition meta as it is about the method name, which is outside the problem domain.

Comment: Note that this question no longer meets Code Review's current standards, as there are too many vague placeholders for a meaningful review.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
def toggle_attribute
  statement1
  @response = yield(
    param1: param1value,
    param2: param2value
  )
  statement2
end

def disable_attribute
  toggle_attribute { |params| Client::Service.disable_attribute(params) }
end

def enable_attribute
  toggle_attribute { |params| Client::Service.enable_attribute(params) }
end
```

If you want to be more succinct, you could:

```
def toggle_attribute(method_name)
  statement1
  @response = Client::Service.send(method_name,
    param1: param1value,
    param2: param2value
  )
  statement2
end

def disable_attribute
  toggle_attribute(:disable_attribute)
end

def enable_attribute
  toggle_attribute(:enable_attribute)
end
```

And if you want to really impress your friends, you could write:

```
def toggle_attribute(method_name)
  statement1
  @response = Client::Service.send(method_name,
    param1: param1value,
    param2: param2value
  )
  statement2
end

def method_missing(method_name, *args)
  %i[disable_attribute enable_attribute].include?(method_name) ? 
    toggle_attribute(method_name) : super
end
```

Comment: Nice answer, Uri.  I'd definitely vote for the second option.

Comment: @Jonah: `method_missing` is a basic example of metaprogramming ;)

Comment: That was the 3rd option, I voted 2nd

Comment: Great answer! I don't think I'd use the term `toggle` in the method name, though, because the method doesn't toggle. Perhaps `set` or `update`.